# Laravel migrate my crud to another project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Sometimes I need use same cruds or modules (includes routes, controllers, models, views) for example "POSTS".
How I can export this module to another project. Exist some method to do this? 
I would appreciate some link to start doing this quickly...

Comment: You can make a base proyect with all the cruds that you will need and then copy this proyect and continue working on the copy. I will keep it on git in a repository and then clone the repository to start a new proyect with all the base cruds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a package with your crud, publish it on the public git repository, publish on the a package manager as packagist and use them in your other projects.

Inside of you package, you can put all the CRUD business logic (migrations, views, controllers...) and more.

This is a great, easy and reusable solution. You only will need configure a service provider of the package into you new laravel application.

You can see more about this here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages